# Makefile - How to check if variable is not empty and is one of the two values

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to check if my `ENVIRONMENT` variable is not empty and is either `development` or `production`.

```
ENVIRONMENT ?= development

define ENV_CHECK
       $(if $(or $(call seq,$(1),development),$(call seq,$(1),production)),true,false)
endef

.PHONY: test
test:
       @echo "$(ENVIRONMENT)"
       $(call ENV_CHECK,$(ENVIRONMENT))
```

My `make test` fails with below error

```
# make test
development
false
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a commonplace sort of solution:

**Makefile**

```
ENVIRONMENT ?= development
ifeq ($(filter $(ENVIRONMENT),development production),)
$(error invalid `ENVIRONMENT` value)
endif 

.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo "$(ENVIRONMENT)"
```

See [8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)